# Power of a point theorem to find the inradius of a right triangle.

Tags: geometry

The question is:

> Prove that the inradius of a right triangle with leg lengths $a$ and $b$ and hypotenuse $c$ is $(a+b-c)/2$

Drawing out an image, I found that certain lengths were equal using the theorem that tangents from the same point are equal, but from that I am unsure how to continue. Any ideas?

My working so far:
[image]

Comment: Have you made an image?

Comment: I quickly drew one, should I add it to the original post?

Comment: I would make it so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $$b-r+a-r=c$$ and now you can compute $r$.
It is $$x=r,z=a-r,y=b-r$$

Comment: Could you explain, how you derived this equation?

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something, but is it obvious that x=r? Assuming that is true, I can see how we get the solution.

Comment: Since we have a right angle in the corner

Comment: That is true. since we have tangent segments from the corner where the right angle is situated

Comment: This is your $x$

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that a radius will always meet a tangent at 90 degrees?

Comment: And we get a square with side length $x=r$

Comment: Yes this is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If you have drawn a diagram, then you should see a square with diagonal $CI$.

Comment: Which point is I, the center of the circle?

Comment: Yes, the incentre.  You should also immediatly see three right-angles, and two pairs of adjacent sides are equal alng the way.